# How to print files which name start by m and does not exceed 6 letters on linux?

Tags: linux

> Hi, how to list files which name start by m and does not exceed 6 letters on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe could execute something like this to get the files in the same folder:

```
 ls | egrep "^m.{0,5}$"
```

If you want to look into subfolders, you can try "find" :

```
find . -type f | egrep "^m.{0,5}$"
```

This way, the first command gets the files, and they are filtered after the pipe with a regular expression, allowing only names beginning with "m" and up to 5 characters more.